# cococs2d everything 20px off on y axis

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Somehow everything is about 20px low on y axis.
I have sprite moving around screen but is limited to screen width & height, this sprite never goes above about 460px & goes below the bottom. There is nothing wrong with my code. I inserted Sprite to check top of screen:

```
CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
sprite.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height);
```

This sprite is properly in the middle of width but about 20 px from the top.

Also when i insert sprite on touchLocation, sprite is also off.
The game is in Portrait view.
Is there something i should be setting?

Comment: check out the anchor point for the sprite, I've not used the iPhone version of cocos in many years, but look for methods like `setAnchorPoint`.

Comment: It seems like the whole layer is off, not the sprite.

Comment: Sounds like it is related to the statusbar offset.

Comment: did you change the position of the layer or scene? All node positions are relative to their parents, so a sprite with position 100,100 in a scene whose position is 0,-20 will actually be at screen coordinate 100,80

Answer (score 0):

You should set the status bar to hidden in the following places:
1. Initially hidden in the app plist
2. If you use any xib make sure it has no status bar.

If those 2 don't help - try setting it in code - look at uiapplication documentation specifically setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation: